# Multiple API calls - many curl reponses

Tags: php, json, curl

I am probably barking at the wrong tree and I will need so pointing into correct direction. I am building WIFI portal. In essence:

1. User puts details in.
2. Details are being sent through cURL to REST post call.

> ```
> <?php
>
> include 'functions.php';
>
> session_start();
>
> $user_mac = $_SESSION["id"];        //user's mac address
> $ap_mac = $_SESSION["ap"];            //AP mac
> $ssid = $_SESSION["ssid"];          //ssid the user is on (POST 2.3.2)
> $time = $_SESSION["t"];             //time the user attempted a request of the portal
> $url = $_SESSION["url"];         //url the user attempted to reach
> $sesh = $_SESSION["rand"];
>
> /*
> //Check what gets send
> echo $user_mac;        
> echo '<br/>';
> echo $ap_mac;         
> echo '<br/>';
> echo $ssid;       
> echo '<br/>';
> echo $time;            
> echo '<br/>';
> echo $url;         
> echo '<br/>';
> echo $sesh;
> echo '<br/>';
> echo $_POST["EMAIL"];
> */
>
> $ch = curl_init();
>
> $service_url = 'https://blablabla.com/rest/wifi/post_test';
>
> $parm =  array(
>       'KEY' => '1',
>       'BOOKING_ID' => $_POST["BOOKING_ID"],
>       'GUEST_NAME' => $_POST["GUEST_NAME"],
>       'EMAIL' => $_POST["EMAIL"],
>       'AP_MAC' => $ap_mac,
>       'USER_MAC' => $user_mac,
>       'SSID' => $ssid,
>       'REACH_ID' => $url,     
>       'LOG_TIME' => $time,
>       'SESH_ID'=> $sesh
>       );
>
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$service_url);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($parm));
>
>
> // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
> //          http_build_query(array('postvar1' => 'value1')));
>
> // get the reposne from serv
>
> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
>
> $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
>
> $jsonString = json_encode($server_output, true);
>
> $data = json_decode($jsonString);
>
>
>
> //show the response
>
>
> echo '<pre>',print_r($data),'</pre>';
>
>     curl_close ($ch);
>
>
>
>
>
>      $macreturned = $data[0]['usermac'];
>      $macreturned1 = $jsonString[0]["usermac"];
>
>   echo    $macreturned;
>   echo    $macreturned1;
>
>
>   $status = $jsonString[0]["Status"];
>
>   $status_id = (int)$status;
>
>
>
>   IF ($status_id == 1 ) {
>
>       echo "Access denied.";
>     }
>   ELSE 
>   {
>       echo "Access provided.";
>
>       sendAuthorization($macreturned,10);
>   }
>
>
>
>
>     curl_close ($ch);
>
>
> ?>
> ```

3. Oracle DB process the input.
4. DB sent response to portal in form o JSON string with data like MAC address and session length.

> {
>      "Status":"2",
>      "usermac":"11:11:11:11:11", 
>      "Return message":"Whoa we are in",
>      "sesh_length":"14400",
>      "sesh_id":"4568"
>   }

3. Oracle DB process the input.

> {
>      "Status":"2",
>      "usermac":"11:11:11:11:11", 
>      "Return message":"Whoa we are in",
>      "sesh_length":"14400",
>      "sesh_id":"4568"
>   }

4. DB sent response to portal in form o JSON string with data like MAC address and session length.
5. Depending on status output it executes another call through function *sendAuthorization*

> ```
> <?php
>
>
> function sendAuthorization($id, $minutes)
> {
>     $unifiServer = "https://1.1.1.1";
>     $unifiUser = "Admin";
>     $unifiPass = "Admin";
>
>     // Start Curl for login
>     $ch = curl_init();
>     // We are posting data
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
>     // Set up cookies
>     $cookie_file = "/tmp/unifi_cookie";
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
>     // Allow Self Signed Certs
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
>     // Force SSL3 only
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
>     // Login to the UniFi controller
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$unifiServer/login");
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
>         "login=login&username=$unifiUser&password=$unifiPass");
>     // send login command
>     curl_exec ($ch);
>
>     // Send user to authorize and the time allowed
>     $data = json_encode(array(
>         'cmd'=>'authorize-guest',
>         'mac'=>$id,
>         'minutes'=>$minutes));
>
>     // Send the command to the API
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/api/cmd/stamgr');
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'json='.$data);
>     curl_exec ($ch);
>
>     // Logout of the UniFi Controller
>     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $unifiServer.'/logout');
>     curl_exec ($ch);
>     curl_close ($ch);
>     unset($ch);
> }
>
>
>
> ?>
> ```

Now this is when it stops working. I need to talk back to controller so I need to execute another function passing two elements usermac with sesh_length using cURL. However after receiving JSON from server something on PHP side of things is stopping executing another cURL function.

Now there are info about multiple cURL scripts running but I need to carry out call CALL depending on results from initial call.

Any help greatly appreciated, I dont work on this side of things so I know very little about PHP and cURL.

Comment: Section 5: `Depending on status output it executes another call through function sendAuthorization`

Does this execute the sendAuthorization function when it should, or is the sendAuthorization function not being called at all? Or is your problem after returning from sendAuthorization? In that case we'd need to see the code for that.

Comment: sendAuthorization is a function that is called upon condition $status !== 1. However I am getting response, I can print it out but  I cannot assign it to variable and then call another function. I hope it helps.

Comment: Okay. So the problem is that it's not executing the `IF ($status_id == 1 ) {...} ELSE {...}` block? If your server returns json, I'm not sure what you're doing with `$jsonString = json_encode($server_output, true);`. What if you access this as an object - `$obj = json_decode($server_output);` and match against `$obj->Status`? The `==` operator will match string and int, so you don't need to cast to int.